# How to convert time (mm:ss) to decimal form

Tags: r, time, numeric

I've imported a CSV file to R using RStudio where I am trying to plot points per game against minutes per game. However the minutes per game is in the format mm: ss and I'm having a hard time finding how to convert it to decimal form.

Comment: What is the class of the variable holding time?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Given that you start with a character vector, this is relatively easy :

```
minPerGame <- c("4:30","2:20","34:10")

sapply(strsplit(minPerGame,":"),
  function(x) {
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    x[1]+x[2]/60
    }
)
```

gives

```
[1]  4.500000  2.333333 34.166667
```

Make sure you checked that you used `read.csv()` with the option `as.is=TRUE`. Otherwise you'll have to convert using `as.character()`.

Comment: I use stuckey <- read.csv("C:/kalle/R/stuckey.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) so I won't get the values as factors and can't seem to get the as.is=TRUE to work.

Comment: @Joe : So you figured out that's the same ;-) Don't forget to accept either answer you found most helpful as the correct one by using the V-sign on the left. This site serves as a reference for other people as well (see also the FAQ). Cheers

Answer (score 9):

Do you *need* to decimalise it? If you store the data in the correct format, for example as an object of class `POSIXlt`, one of R's date-time classes, R will handle the correct handling of the times in numeric fashion. Here is an example of what I mean:

First we create some dummy data for illustration purposes:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(Times = seq(as.POSIXlt("10:00", format = "%M:%S"), 
                             length = 100, by = 10),
                 Points = cumsum(rpois(100, lambda = 1)))
head(DF)
```

Ignore the fact that there are dates here, it is effectively ignored when we do the plot as all observations have the same date part. Next we plot this using R's formula interface:

```
plot(Points ~ Times, data = DF, type = "o")
```

Which produces this:

[image: points per game time]

Comment: conversion to as.numeric to calculate mean game duration becomes tedious though, as `POSIXt` classes take 31/12/1969 23:59:59 as zero, but add the current date when converting. So a naive `mean(as.numeric(Times))` will give a wrong result today, and a different wrong result tomorrow...

Comment: @Joris Agreed, but @Joe asked about plotting, hence I asked if he needed to decimalise. After I'd written my answer I realised you dealt with that explicitly so I didn't bother with it as between us we cover most bases.

Comment: oops, I missed that question about plotting. :-) then very much +1 indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Some tuning of first solution:

```
minPerGame <- paste(sample(1:89,100000,T),sample(0:59,100000,T),sep=":")

f1 <- function(){
sapply(strsplit(minPerGame,":"),
 function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x[1]+x[2]/60
 }
)
}
#
f2<- function(){
 w <- matrix(c(1,1/60),ncol=1)
 as.vector(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(minPerGame,":"))),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)%*%w)
}

system.time(f1())
system.time(f2())
```

> system.time(f1())    user  system elapsed 
>      0.88    0.00    0.86
>
> system.time(f2())    user  system elapsed 
>      0.25    0.00    0.27

Answer (score 0):

I had data with times like so:

- 22:49:20+1100
- 19:29:11+1000
- 20:01:26+0930

And this seemed to work for me:

```
my_df <- my_df %>%
separate(col = eventTime, into = c("H", "M", "S"), sep = "\\:", remove = FALSE) %>% 
separate(col = S, into = c("S", "Z"), sep = "\\+", remove = TRUE) %>% 
separate(col = Z, into = c("ZH", "ZM"), sep = 2, remove = TRUE) %>% 
mutate(H = as.numeric(H)/24) %>% 
mutate(M = as.numeric(M)/24/60) %>% 
mutate(S = as.numeric(S)/24/60/60) %>% 
mutate(ZH = as.numeric(ZH)/24) %>% 
mutate(ZM = as.numeric(ZM)/24/60) %>% 
mutate(H = H-ZH) %>% 
mutate(M = M-ZM) %>% 
mutate(time_num = H+M+S)
```

H:hours,
M:minutes,
S:seconds,
Z:zone,
ZH:zone hours,
ZM:zone minutes

If you don't care about the timezones then this:

```
my_df <- my_df %>%
separate(col = eventTime, into = c("H", "M", "S"), sep = "\\:", remove = FALSE) %>% 
separate(col = S, into = c("S", "Z"), sep = "\\+", remove = TRUE) %>% 
mutate(H = as.numeric(H)/24) %>% 
mutate(M = as.numeric(M)/24/60) %>% 
mutate(S = as.numeric(S)/24/60/60) %>% 
mutate(time_num = H+M+S)
```

The first method you may end up with negatives. The second method you should get values between 0 and 1 with the time_num being the portion of the day.

For example:

- 22:49:20+1100  =  0.950925926
- 07:26:10+1100  =  0.309837963

It should be noted my time data was all from a timezone with a positive +

Answer (score 0):

I like lubridate for this. The same logic could be used for hours+minutes, as well, by adjusting to use `hm` in place of `ms`, etc.

```
minPerGame <- c("4:30","2:20","34:10")

library(lubridate)
minPerGame_ms <- ms(minPerGame)
(minPerGame_dec = minute(minPerGame_ms) + second(minPerGame_ms)/60)
[1]  4.500000  2.333333 34.166667
```