# Convert Time to Fraction and Average in R

Tags: r, datetime

I need to get the mean of times in column "ci" [c]lock-[i]n. The data is in character format, e.g. "8:05 AM". I can use the below code to reformat and get the data to a point wherein I can compute a mean:

```
hrs$ci <- strptime(hrs$ci, format = "%I:%M %p")
mean(hrs$ci)
```

But for some reason when I try to use dcast to create a table...

```
hrs <- dcast(hrs, Office ~ Week, value.var = "ci", fun.aggregate = mean)
```

...it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
Error in dim(ordered) <- ns : dims [product 900] do not match the length of object [9900]
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Or have a suggestion for a better way? In the end I am trying to get the table that the dcast would provide with average clock-in times by week for each office.

Ideally at the end I would have the fraction of a day (i.e. 0.50 = noon) for the time, but I could probably work with alternative formats.

Comment: Could you post as `dput(head(hrs, 20))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out. Probably not the most savvy of approaches, but it works!

First I stripped the AM/PM using the below:

```
hrs$ci <- substr(hrs$ci, 1, 5)
```

This turned the "08:05 AM" into simply "08:05". Then using [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186972/how-to-convert-time-mmss-to-decimal-form-in-r) I converted it to a number:

```
hrs$ci <- sapply(strsplit(hr$ci, ":"),
    function(x) {
        x <- as.numeric(x)
        x[1]+x[2]/60
    }
)
```

Then I divided the output by 24 to get the fraction of a day I was looking for:

```
hrs$ci <- hrs$ci / 24
```

After which I ran the code I had above:

```
hrs <- dcast(hrs, Office ~ Week, value.var = "ci", fun.aggregate = mean)
```

And it works!

Comment: Also, in the event that the AM/PM location is not static, you can use `hrs$ci <- sub(" .*", "", hrs$ci)`.