# Convert time values to numeric while keeping time characteristics

Tags: r, character, numeric, gsub

I have a data set which contains interval times of different events occurring. What I want to do, is convert the data into a numeric vector, so its easier to manipulate and run summaries/make graphs etc, while keeping its time characteristics. Here is a snippet of my data:

```
data <- c( "03:31", "12:17", "16:29", "09:52", "04:01", "09:00", "06:29",
           "04:17", "04:42")
class(data)
[1] character
```

The obvious answer is :

```
as.numeric(data)
```

But I get this error:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I thought of maybe taking the ':' out, but then it loses its time characteristics. By that, I mean that if I sum values together say 347 and 543, it would give me 890 as opposed to 930. Here is the code that I would use to take the colon out, which works fine for its purpose:

```
Nocolon <- gsub("[:]", "", Data, perl=TRUE)
"0331" "1217" "1629" "0952" "0401" "0900" "0629" "0417" "0442"
```

So essentially, what I want is for my time values to be in a form which is easy to manipulate and analyse. My idea is for it to be a numeric vector, but that is from my minimal understanding of R. My actual code has thousands of time values, and I want to create a plot that will allow me to view and determine whether the values follow a statistical distribution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250253/subtracting-times-that-exceed-60-minutes/41252058

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some approaches.  All convert to minutes. For example, the first component is `"03:31"` which is 3 * 60 + 31 = 211 minutes. (1) to (5) do not use any packages.

**1) %*%**  It works by reading `data` into a 2 column data frame with hours and minutes.  That is converted to a matrix so that it can be matrix multiplied by `c(60, 1)`.  Finally, unravel it with `c`.

```
c(as.matrix(read.table(text = data, sep = ":")) %*% c(60, 1))
[1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```

**2) with** This variation is even shorter.  It creates the same data frame but and then simply mulitiplies the first column (`V1`) by 60 and adds it to the second column (`V2`).

```
with(read.table(text = data, sep = ":"), 60*V1+V2)
[1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```

**3) complex**  This converts each component to a complex number and then performs the required arithmetic on the real and imaginary parts:

```
data_c <- as.complex(sub(":(\\d+)", "+\\1i", data))
60 * Re(data_c) + Im(data_c)
## [1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```

**3a)**  This variation of (3) also works and avoids regular expressions:

```
data_c <- as.complex(paste0(chartr(":", "+", data), "i"))
60 * Re(data_c) + Im(data_c)
## [1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```

**4) eval** This converts each component into an arithmetic expression which evaluates to the number of minutes and then performs the evalution.  Using `eval` is not really recommended when you can avoid it so this one is less desirable:

```
sapply(parse(text = sub("(\\d+):", "60*\\1+", data)), eval)
## [1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```

**5) POSIXlt** We can convert to `"POSIXlt"` class and then use the `hour` and `min` components:

```
with(unclass(as.POSIXlt(data, format = "%H:%M")), 60 * hour + min)
## [1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```

**6) chron** Using the chron package we can paste on the seconds, convert to `"times"` class and then convert to minutes:

```
library(chron)
24 * 60 * as.numeric(times(paste0(data, ":00")))
## [1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```

**7) lubridate** Using the lubridate package we can convert it using `hm` and then to numeric giving seconds and finally dividing by 60 to give minutes:

```
as.numeric(hm(data)) / 60
## [1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `as.difftime` function designed for this:

```
as.difftime(data, format="%H:%M", units="mins")
#Time differences in mins
#[1] 211 737 989 592 241 540 389 257 282
```