# How to convert time HH:MM:SS to decimal form in R?

Tags: r, time

I need to turn my time variable (all data formatted in HH:MM:SS) into a a numeric and decimal of the hour.

For example `07:05:00` turns into `7.083` using base R (I'm in a secure lab so can't access packages).

Is there a way to do this using base R code?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5186972/680068

Comment: Feel free to post as answer below. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

You can easily write your own parser:

```
parse_time <- function(x) {
  res <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, ":", TRUE))
  mode(res) <- "numeric"
  c(res %*% (1/c(1, 60, 3600)))
}

parse_time(c("07:05:00","07:05:30"))
#[1] 7.083333 7.091667
```

Answer (score 0):

This was how I managed it in the end:

```
Test$Hours <- as.character(Test$Offence.Start.Time)
Test$Hours <- sapply(strsplit(Test$Hours,":"),
   function(x) {
     x <- as.numeric(x)
     x[1]+x[2]/60})
```