# How to convert character into minutes seconds?

Tags: r, datetime

My data looks like this

```
"3:00", "0:30", "2:35"
```

It is now in a character form, how can I convert it to minutes and seconds in R? I tried the as.Date() function but it is not working.

Here is my code that didn't work:

```
df2$Video_Length = as.Date(df2$Video_Length,'%M:%S')
```

Comment: A time is not a date. And what you have there are not even times. Those are durations.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5186972/680068

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ms` in package `lubridate`

```r
lubridate::ms(c("3:00", "0:30", "2:35"))
#> [1] "3M 0S"  "30S"    "2M 35S"
```